# Smooth expectations outside the exponential family

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, smoothing, exponential-family

At page 85-86 of Young and Smith "Essentials of Statistical Inference" there 
is an interesting result. If $X$ is a r.v. distributed according to the exponential family and $\phi(x)$ is a bounded (but not necessarily differentiable) function of x, then:

$$
E(\phi(x)) = \int \phi(x) c(\theta) h(x) \text{exp} \big(\sum_{i = 1}^k \theta_i \tau_i(x)\big )dx
$$

is differentiable of all orders w.r.t. $\theta$. My interpretation is that taking expectation under the exponential family smooths the function $\phi(x)$. I was wondering if similar "smoothing'' effects take place also outside the exponential family.